# Homebrew shows "You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar" for cabal-install

Tags: macos, haskell, homebrew, cabal

```
$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    cabal-install
```

Should I really run `brew link`?   cabal-install is a separate system that install Haskell softwares and it can be updated in that system.

Comment: As far as I understand, you installed haskell dev tools (ghc, cabal-install) using brew. And then (probably) you updated cabal-install via `cabal install cabal-install`, right? Oh, and please, provide the output of `which cabal`. It may help us to decide either to `brew link` or not.

Comment: You're right.  That's exactly what I did.  `which cabal` outputs `/usr/local/bin/cabal`.